# Increasing framerate from 60 to 90 in Cocos2D V3 no effect

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, frame-rate

In CCAppDelegate I set:

```
NSTimeInterval animationInterval = [(config[CCSetupAnimationInterval] ?: @(1.0/90.0)) doubleValue];
[director setAnimationInterval:animationInterval];

director.fixedUpdateInterval = [(config[CCSetupFixedUpdateInterval] ?: @(1.0/90.0)) doubleValue];
```

and in CCDirectoriOS - startAnimation I set:

```
int frameInterval = (int) floor(_animationInterval * 90.0f);

CCLOG(@"cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: %.2f", 90.0f/frameInterval);
```

But the FPS counter shows 59/60 fps max.

How do I increase the framerate?

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira That's a myth, and certainly the eye's limit isn't 60 fps nor is it 30 fps. You should read this: http://www.100fps.com/how_many_frames_can_humans_see.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real reason is that iOS devices have a fixed screen refresh rate of 60 Hz. You can not display more than 60 frames per second on iOS because the screen doesn't refresh faster than 60 Hz (= times per second). The same is true for just about every other mobile device.

Now on PCs it's rather common to turn vertical synchronisation off and have the GPU render as fast as it can, with all the [screen tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing) you can possibly stand. On mobile devices, VSync is always on and you can not turn it off, ever.

Mobile benchmarking software frequently uses so-called "offscreen render" tests where they render everything into a memory buffer to circumvent the 60 Hz limit and to come up with a theoretically achievable framerate, like 150 fps. Of course you won't see realtime updates of the test on the screen while the test is running.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to increase the frame rate above 60, because the screen refresh rate is 60Hz, so it **would not make any difference** on screen and it would be just waste of battery and CPU.

You could in theory increase it in cocos2d, however you would have to change some code, as cocos2d uses CADisplayLink as its inner timer, which is obviously linked to the display thus giving you max 60 fps. You would have to have your own refresh timer with interval 1.0/90.0. But you still wouldn't see the difference.